# My AltJit not working in iOS 17 iPad when using Mac

Tags: ios, ipad, ios17, altstore

I was trying to enable Jit on my iPad today and I ran into issues.

I ran into this:

> pymobiledevice3 not installed

so I followed the instructions on the official page and did this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pymobiledevice3
```

But then I got another error:

> Could not connect to device. The process 'python3' returned unexpected output. Error: No such command 'start-quic-tunnel

So I followed the instructions and did this:

```
python3 -m pip install pymobiledevice3==2.30.0 construct==2.10.69
```

After it, I tried again and got this error again:

> pymobiledevice3 not installed

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the python binaries directory isn't in your path.
Try replacing:

```
pymobiledevice3
```

With:

```
python3 -m pymobiledevice3
```

Comment: How do you do that?